# Why is etree returning nothing from my SVG when I run `for glyph in font.iter('glyph')`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, lxml, elementtree

## Goal

I am pretty new to Python. I thought I would try to write a script that retrieves `glyph-name` and `unicode` from an SVG icon file using etree to create a LESS file from them.

## Brute Force Solution

I wrote a solution where I iterate over the SVG elements to get the element attributes, put them into a list, and then write my LESS styles from the attributes in the list. It looks something like this:

### SVG Structure

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><!--
2019-3-13: Created with FontForge (http://fontforge.org)
-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <metadata>
Created by FontForge 20170731 at Wed Mar 13 07:05:16 2019 By root
    </metadata>
    <defs>
        <font id="Flaticon" horiz-adv-x="512">
            <font-face font-family="Flaticon" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" units-per-em="512" panose-1="2 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0" ascent="448" descent="-64" bbox="-0.00048785 -64.001 512 448" underline-thickness="25.6" underline-position="-51.2" unicode-range="U+0020-F131" />
            <missing-glyph />
            <glyph glyph-name="space" unicode=" " horiz-adv-x="200" />
            <glyph glyph-name="001-suitcase" unicode="&#xf100;" d="M487.934 315.467c13.2705 0 24.0664 -10.7959 24.0664 -24.0654v-281.637c0 -13.2695 -10.7959 -24.0654 -24.0664 -24.0654h-288.005c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5c0 4.1416 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h164.539v17.3105
c0 0.0136719 -0.00195312 0.0263672 -0.00195312 0.0390625s0.00195312 0.0263672 0.00195312 0.0390625v83.5781h-17.3516c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v82.835c0 4.1416 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h17.3516v83.5771
c0 0.0126953 -0.00195312 0.0253906 -0.00195312 0.0390625c0 0.0126953 0.00195312 0.0253906 0.00195312 0.0390625v17.3105h-216.933v-100.965h17.3486c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5v-82.835c0 -4.1416 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-17.3486v-100.967h22.4248
c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5c0 -4.14258 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-145.891c-13.2705 0 -24.0664 10.7949 -24.0664 24.0654v41.3584c0 0.0195312 -0.00292969 0.0380859 -0.00292969 0.0576172s0.00292969 0.0380859 0.00292969 0.0585938v198.687
c0 0.0205078 -0.00292969 0.0380859 -0.00292969 0.0585938c0 0.0185547 0.00292969 0.0380859 0.00292969 0.0576172v41.3574c0 13.2695 10.7959 24.0654 24.0664 24.0654h41.3838c0.00976562 0 0.0185547 0.000976562 0.0292969 0.000976562
c0.00976562 0 0.0185547 -0.000976562 0.0283203 -0.000976562h91.873v58.7695c0 4.1416 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h17.3516v9.06543c0 4.14258 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h132.532c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5v-9.06543h17.3506c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5v-58.7686h91.8701
c0.00976562 0 0.0185547 0.000976562 0.0283203 0.000976562c0.0107422 0 0.0195312 -0.000976562 0.0292969 -0.000976562h41.3877zM114.401 300.467v-9.84961h18.1338v9.84961h-18.1338zM114.401 275.618v-76.1162h18.1338v76.1162h-18.1338zM15.0029 291.401v-33.3545
c21.8418 3.26855 39.1514 20.5781 42.4189 42.4199h-33.3525c-4.99902 0 -9.06641 -4.06641 -9.06641 -9.06543zM24.0693 0.701172h33.3525c-3.2666 21.8418 -20.5771 39.1523 -42.4189 42.4219v-33.3564c0 -5 4.06738 -9.06641 9.06641 -9.06543zM99.4014 18.0879v83.5781
h-17.3516c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v82.835c0 4.1416 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h17.3516v83.5771c0 0.0126953 -0.00195312 0.0253906 -0.00195312 0.0390625c0 0.0126953 0.00195312 0.0253906 0.00195312 0.0390625h0.000976562v17.3105h-26.8623
c-3.45312 -30.1211 -27.416 -54.085 -57.5371 -57.5381v-184.689c30.1221 -3.4541 54.085 -27.418 57.5371 -57.54h26.8613v17.3105c0 0.0136719 -0.00195312 0.0263672 -0.00195312 0.0390625s0.00195312 0.0263672 0.00195312 0.0390625zM132.535 0.700195v9.84961
h-18.1338v-9.84961h18.1338zM132.535 25.5498v76.1172h-18.1338v-76.1172h18.1338zM157.384 184.501h-67.834v-67.834h67.834v67.834zM304.917 383.302v-18.1338h9.85059v9.03906c0 0.00976562 -0.000976562 0.0185547 -0.000976562 0.0292969
c0 0.00976562 0.000976562 0.0185547 0.000976562 0.0283203v9.03711h-9.85059zM222.084 383.302v-18.1338h67.834v18.1338h-67.834zM197.235 383.302v-18.1338h9.84863v18.1338h-9.84863zM339.619 315.467v51.2686h-9.85059v-9.06836c0 -4.1416 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5
h-132.532c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v9.06836h-9.85156v-51.2686h167.234zM379.469 300.467v-9.84961h18.1328v9.84961h-18.1328zM379.468 275.617v-76.1162h18.1328v76.1162h-18.1328zM354.617 116.666h67.834v67.835h-67.834v-67.835zM397.601 0.700195v9.84961
h-18.1328v-9.84961h18.1328zM397.602 25.5498v76.1172h-18.1328v-76.1172h18.1328zM496.999 9.76562v33.3623c-21.8447 -3.26758 -39.1572 -20.582 -42.4229 -42.4277h33.3574c4.99902 0 9.06641 4.06641 9.06543 9.06543zM497 58.2471v184.682
c-30.123 3.45215 -54.0869 27.416 -57.54 57.5381h-26.8584v-100.965h17.3496c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5v-82.835c0 -4.1416 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-17.3496v-100.966h26.8574c3.4502 30.126 27.416 54.0938 57.541 57.5459zM497 258.046v33.3555
c0 4.99902 -4.06738 9.06543 -9.06641 9.06543h-33.3564c3.26855 -21.8428 20.5801 -39.1523 42.4229 -42.4209zM140.033 174.652c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5v-33.1348c0 -4.1416 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-33.1338c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v33.1348
c0 4.1416 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h33.1338zM132.533 141.518v18.1348h-18.1338v-18.1348h18.1338zM405.1 174.652c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5v-33.1348c0 -4.1416 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-33.1338c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v33.1348c0 4.1416 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5
h33.1338zM397.6 141.518v18.1348h-18.1338v-18.1348h18.1338zM245.676 229.293c1.53516 -2.30078 1.67773 -5.25977 0.373047 -7.69922c-1.30469 -2.4375 -3.84668 -3.96094 -6.61328 -3.96094h-66.2666c-2.76562 0 -5.30664 1.52344 -6.6123 3.96094
c-1.30469 2.43945 -1.16309 5.39844 0.37207 7.69922l33.1318 49.7002c1.39062 2.08691 3.73242 3.33984 6.24023 3.33984c2.50684 0 4.84961 -1.25293 6.24023 -3.33887zM187.182 232.634h38.2402l-19.1211 28.6797zM305.701 83.5381c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.3584 7.5 -7.5
v-49.7051c0 -4.1416 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-82.834c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.3584 -7.5 7.5v49.7051c0 4.1416 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h82.834zM298.201 33.832v34.7051h-67.834v-34.7051h67.834z" />
            <glyph glyph-name="036-travel-trailer" unicode="&#xf123;" d="M156.601 290.617c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5v-82.833c0 -4.14355 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-99.3994c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35645 -7.5 7.5v57.9434c0 0.0136719 -0.00195312 0.0253906 -0.00195312 0.0380859c0 0.0136719 0.00195312 0.0263672 0.00195312 0.0390625
v24.8125c0 4.14258 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h99.3994zM149.101 207.784v42.9814h-84.3994v-42.9814h34.6982v9.06445c0 4.14355 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.35645 7.5 -7.5v-9.06445h34.7012zM149.102 265.766v9.85156h-84.3994v-9.85156h84.3994zM328.066 195.529
c-1.42578 -1.7373 -3.55371 -2.74512 -5.80078 -2.74512h-132.531c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v82.833c0 4.14258 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h115.967c3.57617 0 6.6543 -2.52344 7.35449 -6.0293l4.95605 -24.7852
c0.00390625 -0.0175781 0.00683594 -0.0361328 0.0117188 -0.0537109l11.5977 -57.9941c0.439453 -2.20312 -0.129883 -4.48926 -1.55469 -6.22559zM197.234 275.617v-9.85156h104.289l-1.9707 9.85156h-102.318zM263.5 207.784h49.6182l-8.59473 42.9814h-107.288v-42.9814
h51.2646v9.06445c0 4.14355 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5s7.5 -3.35645 7.5 -7.5v-9.06445zM73.7666 124.951c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5v-33.1328c0 -4.14355 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-33.1338c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35645 -7.5 7.5v33.1328c0 4.14258 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5
h33.1338zM66.2666 91.8184v18.1328h-18.1338v-18.1328h18.1338zM189.736 91.8184c22.4033 0 40.6318 -18.2275 40.6318 -40.6338c0 -22.4033 -18.2275 -40.6318 -40.6318 -40.6318c-22.4053 0 -40.6328 18.2275 -40.6328 40.6318c0 22.4053 18.2285 40.6338 40.6328 40.6338
zM189.736 25.5518c14.1328 0 25.6318 11.498 25.6318 25.6318c0 14.1348 -11.498 25.6338 -25.6318 25.6338c-14.1348 0 -25.6328 -11.499 -25.6328 -25.6338c0 -14.1338 11.499 -25.6318 25.6328 -25.6318zM504.5 91.8184c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.50195v-33.1338
c0 -4.14258 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-17.3496v-9.06543c0 -4.14355 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35645 -7.5 7.5v9.06543h-17.3506c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v9.06641h-52.4678c-3.16016 -9.6084 -12.2119 -16.5664 -22.8633 -16.5664
l-108.845 0.000976562c-1.72949 -17.0488 -9.29785 -32.3896 -20.6562 -44.0146c-0.176758 -0.222656 -0.365234 -0.44043 -0.571289 -0.646484c-0.207031 -0.206055 -0.424805 -0.394531 -0.647461 -0.571289c-13.3057 -13.001 -31.4854 -21.0361 -51.5137 -21.0361
c-20.0312 0 -38.2119 8.03711 -51.5186 21.041c-0.22168 0.175781 -0.436523 0.363281 -0.641602 0.568359c-0.205078 0.204102 -0.392578 0.420898 -0.568359 0.642578c-11.3604 11.624 -18.9307 26.9668 -20.6602 44.0176h-92.2803
c-13.2705 0 -24.0664 10.7969 -24.0664 24.0674v248.498c0 13.2715 10.7959 24.0664 24.0664 24.0664h42.2002v18.1338h-25.6338c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35645 -7.5 7.5v33.1338c0 4.14258 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h36.2969c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5s-3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5
h-28.7969v-18.1338h233.501v18.1338h-174.734c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5s3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5h182.234c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5v-33.1338c0 -4.14355 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-25.6318v-18.1318h25.6318c47.5664 0 87.165 -37.1494 90.1523 -84.5742
c0.136719 -1.78711 5.12109 -57.3945 10.082 -112.673v-0.00488281c2.16992 -24.1826 4.33496 -48.292 6.08887 -67.8145h51.8428v9.06641c0 4.14258 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h17.3506v1.56445h-0.783203c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5c0 4.14355 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5
h16.5664c4.14258 0 7.5 -3.35645 7.5 -7.5c0 -4.14258 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-0.783203v-1.56445h17.3496zM81.2666 358.45v-18.1338h167.236v18.1338h-26.4189v-0.783203c0 -4.14258 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5s-7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v0.783203h-34.7002v-0.783203
c0 -4.14258 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v0.783203h-34.6992v-0.783203c0 -4.14258 -3.35742 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v0.783203h-26.418zM15 316.25v-141.599h241.001c2.50781 0 4.84863 -1.25293 6.24023 -3.34082
l14.3408 -21.5107h97.1211c-4.50781 50.2412 -9.32227 103.961 -9.38672 104.997c-2.49121 39.5439 -35.5156 70.5195 -75.1826 70.5195h-265.067c-4.99902 0 -9.06641 -4.06738 -9.06641 -9.06641zM15 159.651v-9.85156h224.434
c2.50879 0 4.84961 -1.25293 6.24023 -3.33984l14.3408 -21.5117h115.918c-0.290039 3.22852 -0.584961 6.52051 -0.883789 9.85156h-102.481c-2.50879 0 -4.84961 1.25293 -6.24023 3.33984l-14.3398 21.5117h-236.987zM247.717 43.6855c-4.1416 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5
c0 4.14355 3.3584 7.5 7.5 7.5h0.289062c-1.35547 10.5986 -5.54102 20.3193 -11.7803 28.3838l-0.186523 -0.1875c-1.46387 -1.46387 -3.38379 -2.19629 -5.30273 -2.19629s-3.83887 0.732422 -5.30371 2.19629c-2.92871 2.92871 -2.92871 7.67676 0 10.6074
l0.1875 0.185547c-8.06445 6.23926 -17.7852 10.4238 -28.3828 11.7812v-0.288086c0 -4.14258 -3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5c-4.14258 0 -7.5 3.35742 -7.5 7.5v0.288086c-10.5996 -1.35645 -20.3203 -5.54102 -28.3848 -11.7793l0.1875 -0.186523
c2.92871 -2.92969 2.92871 -7.67676 0 -10.6074c-1.46387 -1.46289 -3.38379 -2.19629 -5.30273 -2.19629s-3.83887 0.732422 -5.30371 2.19629l-0.1875 0.188477c-6.23926 -8.06543 -10.4248 -17.7861 -11.7852 -28.3818h0.290039c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5
s-3.3584 -7.5 -7.5 -7.5h-0.291016c1.35742 -10.5996 5.54199 -20.3203 11.7812 -28.3857l0.188477 0.189453c2.92871 2.92773 7.67773 2.92773 10.6064 0c2.92871 -2.92871 2.92871 -7.67676 0 -10.6074l-0.189453 -0.188477
c8.06543 -6.23926 17.7861 -10.4248 28.3857 -11.7822v0.291016c0 4.14258 3.35742 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.1416 0 7.5 -3.35742 7.5 -7.5v-0.291016c10.5986 1.35742 20.3193 5.54199 28.3848 11.7812l-0.188477 0.1875c-2.92871 2.92969 -2.92871 7.67676 0 10.6074
c2.92969 2.92773 7.67871 2.92773 10.6074 0l0.188477 -0.189453c6.23926 8.06543 10.4248 17.7852 11.7812 28.3838h-0.289062zM371.969 58.6846c4.99902 0 9.06641 4.06836 9.06543 9.06641c0 0.313477 -0.015625 0.623047 -0.0449219 0.924805
c-0.00585938 0.0566406 -0.0126953 0.112305 -0.0175781 0.168945c-0.681641 7.5918 -2.03711 22.6768 -3.69141 41.1045h-121.279c-2.50781 0 -4.84961 1.25293 -6.24121 3.33984l-14.3398 21.5117h-220.42v-67.0488c0 -5 4.06738 -9.06738 9.06641 -9.06738h92.2812
c1.72949 17.0459 9.2959 32.3828 20.6504 44.0059c0.179688 0.226562 0.370117 0.447266 0.579102 0.65625c0.209961 0.208984 0.429688 0.400391 0.657227 0.579102c13.3047 12.9951 31.4785 21.0254 51.502 21.0254h0.000976562h0.000976562h0.00195312
c20.0186 -0.00195312 38.1904 -8.03027 51.4941 -21.0225c0.228516 -0.180664 0.452148 -0.373047 0.664062 -0.583984c0.210938 -0.210938 0.402344 -0.43457 0.583984 -0.664062c11.3486 -11.6221 18.9111 -26.9551 20.6406 -43.9951zM497 58.6846v18.1338h-34.7002
v-18.1338h34.7002z" />
        </font>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

```py
from lxml import etree

filename = "font.svg"
tree = etree.parse(open(filename, 'r'))

# Brute Force Method: Iterate through everything and then iterate through attributes.
for element in tree.iter():
    attributes = []

    for name, value in element.attrib.items():
        if (name == "glyph-name") or (name == "unicode"):
            attributes.insert(0, value)

    if type(attributes) != 'bool' and len(attributes) == 2:

        lessPreStyle += '''\
            .icon-{name} {{
                &:before {{
                    content: {unicode};
                }}
            }}
            '''.format(name=attributes[0], unicode=repr(attributes[1]).replace('\\u', '\\'))
```

## Elegant Solution

Now I am trying to make it more efficient by iterating only over the glyphs instead of every element and directly getting the attributes from an object instead of iterating over the attributes to check if it is called `glyph-name` or `unicode`. So far, I have something like this:

```py
# Go directly to the parent of the glyphs
font = tree.getroot()[1][0]

# Filter only glyphs
for glyph in font.iter('glyph'):
    print (glyph.attrib['unicode'])
    print (glyph.attrib['glyph-name'])
```

My current issue is that `for glyph in font.iter('glyph')` returns nothing. According to [Python 3.6.8 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) I should be able to filter the children elements by entering the name of the children I want in the `iter()` function. However, I'm getting nothing. If I remove the filter and just print the tag names of the children, I get all of the tag names. I don't want to have to iterate and check individual elements like last time. Am I missing something here? Or is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: It's probably the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. See here:https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces or here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces depending on whether you're using lxml or ElementTree (can't tell). I'd test for you but since your XML input is a screenshot I don't have time to recreate it.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using `lxml`. I have added the imports and an example SVG file that should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SVG has a default namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`).

To specify a namespace in `iter()` you have to use Clark Notation. This is basically the namespace uri and local name together: `{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}glyph`

You can also use `*` instead of the actual namespace uri to match an element in any namspace: `{*}glyph`

See [here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) and [here](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm) for additional information.

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("font.svg")

# Filter only glyphs
for glyph in tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}glyph'):
    print(glyph.attrib['unicode'])
    print(glyph.attrib['glyph-name'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and additional documentation! That will give me a lot more to look into now.